# Arbitrary intersection of compact subspaces is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm looking at the one-point compactification theorem in Munkres' Topology.  Let $Y$ be the proposed one-point compactification of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$.  Then the arbitrary union of sets of type $Y - C$ where $C$ is a compact subspace of $X$ is another set of that type.  In symbols

$$
\cup (Y - C_{\beta}) = Y - (\cap C_{\beta})
$$

So are arbitrary intersections of compact sets compact in this setting and how?

Edit.  So since $\cap C_{\beta}$ is closed, being an arbitrary intersection of compact (thus closed in a Hausdorff space), choose any $C_{\alpha}$ then $\cap C_{\beta}$ is a closed subset of a compact space $C_{\alpha}$ and so is also compact.

Comment: In Hausdorff spaces, compact subspaces are closed.

Comment: I know that.  But is the closed subspace $\cap C_{\beta}$ compact then?

Comment: I added an edit to my post, is that right?

Comment: Take an open cover of $\cap C_{\beta}$. It is a cover for $C_{\beta_0}$ for some fixed $\beta_0$. Therefore, it has a finite subcover ...

Comment: Yes, the argument in your edit is correct. $\bigcap C_\beta$ is a closed subspace of any of the $C_\alpha$, hence compact.

Comment: Ah, now you can convert your own edit as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $\bigcap_{\beta\in B} C_\beta$. Then $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{Y-C_\beta\}_{\beta\in B}$ is an open cover of any fixed $C_{\beta_0}$ (in fact it covers $Y$), hence there is a finite subcover for $C_{\beta_0}$ and also for $\bigcap C_\beta$. Note that any $Y-C_\beta$ can be dropped from this subcover.